# How to speed up WP_Posts_List_Table __construct() Query on a wordpress website with over 1 million posts?

Tags: posts, wp-query, sql

On a website with over 1 million posts, the following from `class WP_Posts_List_Table __construct()` is taking a long time:

```
SELECT COUNT( 1 )
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
AND post_status NOT IN ( 'trash','auto-draft','inherit','request-pending','request-confirmed','request-failed','request-completed','wc-checkout-draft' )
AND post_author = 1
```

Since `post_author = 1` has many posts, this takes a long time to execute. For post_authors without any post, this query is fast. One way of speeding this up is adding a condition such that this query doesn't run when `post_author = 1`. Is there any other better way to do this without having to edit core wordpress files since there are no hooks in this query?

Comment: it is possible to filter wpdb query https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query/ but that should be as the last option. Maybe try EXPLAIN on the query in sql to try to understand if indexing could help.